# React Native: Using Hooks in Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render a `FlatList`:

```
  <FlatList
    removeClippedSubviews
    numColumns={1}
    {...{ data }}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={object => renderItem(object)}
  />
```

It, of course, works fine with the below function.

```
function renderItem(object) {
  return <Text>Test</Text>;
}
```

However, when adding React Hooks, such that:

```
function renderItem(object) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState("bar");
  return <Text>{foo}</Text>;
}
```

RN returns:

```
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
```

Hooks work elsewhere in the codebase, so it's not a package mismatch issue. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot call hooks inside functional component. You can instead convert functions to functional components

```
  <FlatList
    removeClippedSubviews
    numColumns={1}
    {...{ data }}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={object => <TextComponent item={object} />}
  />


function TextComponent ({item}) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState("bar");
  return <Text>{foo}</Text>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I followed your suggestion and refactored the function to be: `renderItem={object => <renderItem {...{ object }} />}` and destructured object in the function.

Comment: consider using useCallback for your renderItem function, avoiding list expensive re-rendering

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the rules when you work with hooks, You can't declare a `hook`, like this.

You must declare the hook in your top level. If you do this, React can't understand that this is a `hook`.

Here are the rules which you need to follow while working with hooks
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `renderItem` example didn’t work is because the function was neither capitalized nor starting with `use`. This is not special javascript, just a convention defined by the React team. If you change to `function RenderItem` you won’t get the hook error. `renderItem` *is* a component because it takes in data and returns JSX, it just needs to be appropriately capitalized to use hooks.

Then you can do `renderItem={RenderItem}`.